# how to put same two attribute a HTML element?

Tags: html

how to put same two attributes to a HTML element??
example:

```
target="MYIFRAME" target="_blank"
```

"myiframe" is my IFRAME name

Comment: That would not be valid html, how can you have two different targets? It wouldnt know which to use.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Tell us your original plan, and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to put two identical attributes on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not permitted. You cannot have two targets for one element. You can simulate it via javascript, where the JS code opens one target, and the target attribute takes care of the other one.